# Equal strings are not equal in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, equality, nagios

Please help me to understand one strange problem in equality of strings.
This is the code I'm talking about:

```
my $test=undef;
foreach my $List (@o_descrL) {
  if (!($test)) {
    $test = defined($o_noreg)
      ? $descr_d eq $List
      : $descr_d =~ /$List/i;
      printf("$descr_d = $List\t\t==> $test\n");
   }
}
```

Unfortunately I didn't write it but I have to understand it. `$List` is always "SQL Server (C4)", `$descr_d` is changing according to actual item in array. Part of the printed output is here:

```
Power = SQL Server (C4)         ==>
SQL Server (C4) = SQL Server (C4)               ==>
SNMP Service = SQL Server (C4)          ==>
Network Connections = SQL Server (C4)           ==>
```

As you can see, strings in the second line of the output are equal. So why isn't `$test` true?

EDIT: I've printed some more output and found out that when `$descr_d eq $List`, it equals, but not if `$descr_d =~ $List`. Could you please explain what is actually putting to the `$test` variable? I don't understand what does `defined() ? :` mean in here.

EDIT2: For a string "SQL Server Agent" the script works just fine, there is a problem only when (C4) is attached. Quite strange, isn't it?

Comment: You have failed to mention if `defined($o_noreg)` is true or not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When a string is interpolated as a regex, it isn't matched literally, but interpreted as a regex. This is useful to build complex regexes, e.g.

```
my @animals = qw/ cat dog goldfish /;
my $animal_re = join "|", @animals;

say "The $thing is an animal" if $thing =~ /$animal_re/i;
```

In the string `$animal_re`, the `|` is treated as a regex metacharacter.

Other metacharacters are e.g. `(...)`, which is a *capture group*. This is present in your `$List`. That is, your regex is actually looking for the string `SQL Server C4` and capturing the `C4` when successful.

To deactivate metacharacters, you can quote them like

```
/\Q$metachars\E/
```

In your case:

```
$test = defined($o_noreg)
      ? $descr_d eq $List
      : $descr_d =~ /\Q$List/i;
```

As an aside, Perl's default false value is the empty string. Your output may be more readable if you force it to a number, e.g via `$test += 0`. It might also be helpful to print out the strings enclosed in quotes:

```
print qq("$descr_d" = "$List"\t==> $test\n);
```

---

#### Re: your edit

The *conditional operator* is common in C-like languages. It consists of three parts:

```
COND ? EXPR_A : EXPR_B
```

If the condition `COND` is true, the expression `EXPR_A` is evaluated; otherwise, `EXPR_B` is. In your code, the value of the expression that was evaluated is assigned to `$test`.

The `defined` builtin tests whether the value the scalar holds is `undef`. If that is the case, it returns a false value, or `1` otherwise. This is used for some configuration here: When `$o_noreg` is set to any value except `undef`, default string comparison will be used. If it is `undef`, the regex will be executed.

#### Re: edit 2

No it isn't strange: `SQL Server (C4)` contains the `(` and `)` metacharacters, whereas `SQL Server Agent` contains no metacharacters whatsoever.

Comment: @TLP might be nitpicking, ie. `/\Q$List/` vs `/\Q$List\E/` but it's hard to tell

Comment: @mpapec The closing escape sequence is optional.